# Node JS throwing error 'PXL' is undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js

I installed pxl in my node js application but still it says undefined.

Can anyone please let me know if I am missing any installation?

Comment: How did you install it, and what command are you running which throws the error?

Comment: I installed with this command "npm install pxl --save".

Comment: check package.json if it's registered there?

Comment: It is registered in package.json file.

Answer (score 0):

welcome to StackOverflow. Please share your code, so that we can understand it better.

Maybe you have installed the pxl but didn't declare it in your script. Also, check the scope of your declaration.

Comment: I have declared pxl in the script ... but one thing I installed pxl locally but not globally.. May be I can install globally and check once.. Thanks for the post.